# Can I drag a gridsplitter using an image that floats above it?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, gridsplitter

I have a vertical gridsplitter with a column width of 10 pixels. I've floated an icon over the top of it, and using a multibinding, this icon stays centred on the gridsplitter (so it follows the gridsplitter as it's dragged left and right).

Is there a way I can (a) allow the user to the drag the icon only left and right within the grid (I'm guessing by tracking the delta values?), and (b) bind the grid column widths to its position, so that the gridsplitter effectively follows it?

I can see a very rough solution in my head, but I'm wondering if I'm overcomplicating things - maybe there's a simple way to do this through binding?

Comment: `IsHitTestVisible = false` on the icon?

Comment: If it were me, I'd just make a custom copy of the GridSplitter style template, put the icon in center of the template with a negative margin to each side so it pokes out and give it the only hit area. Then just plop the style declaration on the instance and voila.

Comment: Ooh - I like both of those. Thanks .. will give them a try!

Comment: Chris. The downside with negative margins is that the image is drawn outside the bounds of the grid. Is there any way around this?

Comment: I ran into a few other problems as well, so I'm walking away from this and following a more simple solution - thanks anyway!

Comment: Remember to do the @theirname thing so folks get notified of the response. I just happened to look back at this. There's always a way, I just don't know enough about the visualized output you're looking for to respond competently.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisW. - duly noted!